# Collaborative Realtime Mapping with Firebase not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase

I am fairly new to JS and the Google Maps API. I am trying to go through the basic tutorial Google has provided [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/firebase) to map in realtime. I am using Sublime Text and saving the html and .js files on my server. I have set up a Firebase account and referenced it. I cannot get the javascript to properly feed the latitude and longitude to my Firebase database.

Here is my html & css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyByiF_oXuIND_HKTnWb2EYjuHazdhi8F_k
        &libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script src="map.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
 var firebase = new Firebase(
    "https://spatialform.firebaseio.com/# KDyLsffRQiYNSsPGBVW|77ec456e3f094217dc4cbe36f45256f4"
);

function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
        lat: 39.6017,
        lng: -110.7970
    },
    zoom: 14,
    styles: [{
        featureType: 'poi',
        stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }] // Turn off points of interest.
    }, {
        featureType: 'transit.station',
        stylers: [{
                visibility: 'off'
            }] // Turn off bus stations, train stations, etc.
    }],
    disableDoubleClickZoom: false
});
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: e.latLng.lat(),
            lng: e.latLng.lng()
        },
        firebase.push({
            lat: e.latLng.lat(),
            lng: e.latLng.lng()
        });
        map: map
    });
});

firebase.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    var newPosition = snapshot.val();
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newPosition.lat,
        newPosition.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });
});
}
```

All I get is the basic map. I can navigate it, but that is it.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd suggest not sharing your map api key with the whole world and edit/mask your script src above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error with your code: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

This is not valid:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
        lat: e.latLng.lat(),
        lng: e.latLng.lng()
    },
    firebase.push({  // <---- error
        lat: e.latLng.lat(),
        lng: e.latLng.lng()
    });
    map: map
});
```

separate the access to firebase from the marker constructor:

```
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
  firebase.push({
    lat: e.latLng.lat(),
    lng: e.latLng.lng()
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: e.latLng.lat(),
      lng: e.latLng.lng()
    },
    map: map
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0rmtLes/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your call to `firebase.push` is misplaced. I'd put it after creating `marker`.

I would also put some `console.log`s around to understand what is happening exactly. Chrome dev tools, network tab also helps a lot to understand if you are actually accessing to firebase server.